# MS-Access Query Syntax

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have background of mysql. Now I am working on MS-Access with C#. I tried following sql queries but it throws exception

Queries 1:

```
String strSql = "Select * from Employees orderby EmployeeID desc limit 1;";
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, conn);
adapter.Fill(dt);

String strSql = "Select * from Employees orderby EmployeeID asc limit 1;";
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, conn);
adapter.Fill(dt);
```

Common Exception 1:

```
Additional information: Syntax error in FROM clause.
```

Queries 2:

```
String strSql = "select * from Employees where EmployeeID = (select min(EmployeeID) from Employees where EmployeeID < '" + Int64.Parse(this.txtBoxID.Text) + "');";
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, conn);
adapter.Fill(dt);

String strSql = "select * from Employees where EmployeeID = (select min(EmployeeID) from Employees where EmployeeID > '" + Int64.Parse(this.txtBoxID.Text) + "');";
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, conn);
adapter.Fill(dt);
```

Common Exception 2:

```
Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
```

My Database is below

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you create your queries in access using the query designer, change to sql view and then copy the sql back into your code?

Also, I think with access you have to put-

```
SELECT TOP 1 * from Employees;
```

Rather than

```
Select * from Employees limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

And query 1:

```
Select * from Employees order by EmployeeID ...
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, but when I write `orderby` instead of `order by`, it give exception saying : `Additional information: Syntax error in order by clause.`